# Excel Interop difference between [], get_Item() and Item[]

Tags: c#, excel, interop

What´s the difference between those 3 ways:

```
Application xlApp = new Application();
Workbooks xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
Workbook xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(filePath);
Sheets xlSheets = xlWorkbooks.Sheets;

// 1. Way
Worksheet xlSheet = xlSheets["SheetName"] as Worksheet;

// 2. Way
Worksheet xlSheet = xlSheets.Item["SheetName"] as Worksheet;

// 3. Way
Worksheet xlSheet = xlSheets.get_Item("SheetName") as Worksheet;
```

The 1. Way is described as

> Indexer object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets.this  
>   Reserved for internal use.

The 2. Way:

> Indexed property object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets.Item 
>   
>  Returns a single object from a collection.

And the 3. Way:

> [object Index]:object

(for this way, ReSharper recommends to use the 2. way.)

So, all 3 ways do exactly the same, but which one is the recommended and what are the differences?
I think all COMObject Collections have these 3 possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference, pick whatever you like.  Most programmers will probably use `// 1. Way` but if Resharper complains about it then feel free to give in to its demands.  Resharper probably objects because it treats Sheets like a .NET class instead of a COM interface.  It can be forgiven for that, Microsoft fumbled this a bit.

I'll explain why you are given the choice.  The C# language always had a pretty strict definition of a property.  What the C# designers did not like were properties that take argument(s), other than the One and Only, [the indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) of a class (this[]).  Such properties are however pretty common in COM, especially so in Office interop.

COM also has a notion of an indexer, roughly, the default property of a class is special.  It is the property that has [DispId(0)].  And just like the C# indexer it does not have to be named in an expression.

The quirk with the Sheets.Item property is that it has the wrong [DispId].  For some reason it is 170 instead of 0.  The default property is [Sheets._Default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets._default.aspx).  Which is the property you'll use in `// 1. Way`.  No idea how this happened, quacks like an oversight ~19 years ago that they could not correct anymore.

The C# team gave in at version 4 and allowed indexed properties to be used on COM interfaces.  Which is why you have a choice, the get_Item() method needed to be used in earlier versions, the Item property is now supported as well.  There is no difference at all at runtime.